# IntelliJ IDEA does not save my source code before Gradle "test" task

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using IntelliJ IDEA. And my IDE saves my source code automatically before each compile. I am so accustomed to this feature so I even forgot that IDEA does this for me. Looks like whenever I ran Gradle "test" task, IDEA does not saves my source code automaticly, so test results might be incorrect.
Console output almost allways it looks like this:

```
some-task : UP-TO-DATE
```

But if I save source code manually everything works fine.

Is there a way to overcome this problem without manually saving source code before each test run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the Settings dialog (CTRL + ALT + S on Windows) under the Project Settings > Compiler section there is a setting called 'Make project automatically'. Perhaps enabling that setting will cause the changes to be saved as you go (and avoiding your problem)?